# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли тире в след предложении: "в легких дыхание везикулярное"? и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, по существующим правилам, тире здесь не нужно, но, возможно, в контексте другая ситуация, в которой есть противопоставление: в бронхах дыхание жесткое, а в легких - везикулярное". В этом случае налицо неполное предложение, значит, возможно интонационное тире. Кроме того, в профессиональной речи встречаются случаи, когда, как в Вашем примере, возможно выделительное тире, которое делает логическое ударение на характеристике какого-то явления, в данном случае - дыхания.

Comment: несмотря на профессиональную сторону данного высказывания, оно отражает норму, логического ударения нет. заспорила с преподавателем, говоря, что тире не нужно. спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Уважаемая Helen! Если Вас устроил мой ответ,кликните, пожалуйста, слева от ответа символ - поднятый вверх большой палец руки